# Events on the Shield UI Chart legend

Tags: javascript, shieldui

I now need to rephrase my question, because it has been put on hold. Of course I tried to add some events functionality on the starting with the documentation. We have

```
chartLegend: {     
     legendItemSettings: {         
     }
}
```

but nowhere are there any events like

```
events: {     
      click: function(args) {         
      }
}
```

or similar. Nevertheless I didn't post any code, simply because it made no sense at that point. I also tried to insert events code like that:

```
chartLegend: {     
   events: {     
       click: function(args) {         
       }
   }
}
```

but it is not working.

These were the reasons I didn't post any code but only asked my question, which is is there way, to take use of chart legend events- one way or another.

Comment: I now hope hat the hold on my question will be removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no explicit events for the legend items. However you can obtain the same functionality using the corresponding series events: 
For instance :

```
seriesClick - called when the user clicks on a series
seriesMouseOver - called when the user hovers over a series
seriesMouseOut - called when the mouse leaves the series
seriesVisibilityChange - called when a series is hidden or shown
```

and so on.